# Ionic 4 ion-menu not working on Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

Cordova: 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1) -
Ionic: 4.10.3

I have created a project with CLI command:

```
ionic start testApp sidemenu --type="angular"
```

The problem is when the app starts on my physical device Android 4.4.2
and I clicked on the menu, is not opened.

I have enabled polyfills but nothing.

With previous version 3 I have no problem. Ion-menu is working.

```
ionic start testApp sidemenu --type="ionic-angular"
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: any solutions found?

Comment: No and I think it is not possible because of Angular 7 in ionic 4. Angular 7 or 6 does not support es5. So I used ionic 3. That is my guess.